# Why is the outer measure of these sets the same?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568860/if-a-has-lebesgue-outer-measure-0-then-so-does-b-left-x2-x-in-a-right) question, it is stated that$$ \mu^*(B)=\inf \left\{\sum_{i \geq 1} (b_i^2-a_i^2): (a_i^2, b_i^2) \subseteq \mathbb{R}, A\subseteq \bigcup_{i\geq 1} (a_i, b_i)     \right\}$$

is made, where $B = \{x^2 : x \in A\}$, and $\mu^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Why is this true? I have been able to show
$$
\mu^*(B) \leq\inf \left\{\sum_{i \geq 1} (b_i^2-a_i^2): (a_i^2, b_i^2) \subseteq \mathbb{R}, A\subseteq \bigcup_{i\geq 1} (a_i, b_i)     \right\}
$$

but I do not know how to show the other direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not correct.

Take $A=(-1,1)$ Then with $a_1=-1, b_1 = 1$ the first formula gives
$\mu^*B = 0$, which is incorrect.

The second formula cannot be correct either, for the same reason.